# `FullSimplify` is failing to combine terms with `DiracDelta` functions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, diracdelta

`DiracDelta[x] + Pi DiracDelta[x] == (1 + Pi)  DiracDelta[x]` is obviously true by inspection. And yet, `FullSimplify[DiracDelta[x] + Pi  DiracDelta[x] == (1 + Pi)  DiracDelta[x]]` simply returns the expression instead of simplifying to `True`. Why?

Mathematica v14.0.0.0.

Comment: `DiracDelta[x] + Pi  DiracDelta[x] // Factor`

Answer (score 5):

```
FullSimplify[
 DiracDelta[x] + Pi DiracDelta[x] == (1 + Pi) DiracDelta[x], 
 TransformationFunctions -> Expand]
```

> True

---

The documentation states:

`DiracDelta[x] returns 0 for all real numeric x other than 0.`

Both of the following evaluate to `True` automatically.

```
FullSimplify[
 DiracDelta[x] + Pi DiracDelta[x] == (1 + Pi) DiracDelta[x], 
 x ∈ PositiveReals]

FullSimplify[
 DiracDelta[x] + Pi DiracDelta[x] == (1 + Pi) DiracDelta[x], 
 x ∈ NegativeReals]
```

For the case where `x = 0`:

```
DiracDelta[x] + Pi DiracDelta[x] == (1 + Pi) DiracDelta[x] // Expand
```

returns `True`. Hence the use of `TransformationFunctions` above.

Comment: It works if you include `Factor` in the `TransformationFunctions` as well. It's weird to me that Mathematica automatically evaluates `DiracDelta[x] + 2 DiracDelta[x]` to `3 DiracDelta[x]`, but not only does it not do an equivalent evaluation for `DiracDelta[x] + Pi DiracDelta[x]`, but it doesn't even (by default) recognize that equivalence if you give it to it and then try to `FullSimplify` it.

Comment: Someone familiar with the development aspect would know more. Please wait for an answer that explains it better.

Comment: `DiracDelta` is not a usual function, but an attempt to implement the $\delta$-distribution in Mathematica. In the fifties of the 20-th century there were attempts to define the values of distributions  at the reals and the definite integrals over distributions. These attempts are described, for example, in Mikusinskii Jan, Piotr Antosik, Roman Sikorski: Theory of distributions – the sequential approach. Elsevier 1973. It appeared  that is not very successful  and  useful. For example,  Walter Rudin, Functional analysis doesn't even mention it.